# Real positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

is there a theory for real positive (semi-)definite matrices? Here, a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is called positive definite (resp. positive semidefinite) if $x^\top A x > 0$ (resp. $x^\top A x\geq 0$, for all $x\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$. Note that $A$ needs not be symmetric.

For instance, it is known that a positive definite matrix is a $P$-matrix (i.e., all its principal minors are positive), cf. Generating method 4.2 in "Generating and detecting matrices with positive principal minors", Tsatsomeros, 2002. However, all $P$-matrices are not necessarily positive definite.

My question: Is there an existing theory for positive definite matrices? Such as Cholesky-like decompositions, matrix inequalities, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes there are many, many results concerning positive [semi-]definite matrices. Are you asking if there is a designated field/area of mathematics that specifically studies this? "Matrix analysis" might be one place you can find a lot of results on P[S]D matrices.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm asking whether there are any available written results on the account of these matrices. Which "Matrix analysis" book are you referring to? In Chapter 7 of "Matrix Analysis" by Horn and Johnson, they treat the complex case. However, for a complex matrix to be positive semidefinite (i.e., $\bar x^\top Ax\geq 0, \forall x\in\mathbb C^n$), it is necessary and sufficient for it to be Hermitian and PSD. I am mostly interested in real matrices $A$ whose symmetric component $(1/2)(A+A^\top)$ is PSD in the usual sense of symmetric matrices. Thanks!